# Join server to active directory without adding login via AD

Tags: active-directory

Everything I've found so far about joining an Ubuntu machine to a Windows Active Directory domain includes allowing logging in to the Ubuntu machine using user accounts from the Active Directory. I've been told I need to add my server to the office AD domain, but I don't want any extra users to be able to log in to the server besides the ones that have already been locally configured. Are there any tools that separate this functionality so that I can set it up in this way?

I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS, and I'm fairly new to Linux in general.

Answer (score 0):

To configure Ubuntu as domain member, [there is a good tutorial for that.](https://www.tecmint.com/join-ubuntu-to-active-directory-domain-member-samba-winbind/)

`Winbind` and `Samba` are your friends